# Cannot switch back to bottom navigation from react-native-paper-tabs

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-paper

Problem: I have build a structure using react-native-paper bottom navigation. One of the bottom tabs is ''Info" which is implemented using react-native-paper-tabs.
It works fine when I get into it, but gives error when I switch back to my bottom tab navigator

For example Home -> Info (Works fine) {Also the swipe is working fine } ------x (Switching back to any bottom navigator option produces the error.)----

[image]

Now if I will try to switch back to any screen other than "Info" tab it will give error.

[image]

"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.1",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.0",
**"react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.15",**
**"react-native-paper": "^4.12.0",**
**"react-native-paper-tabs": "^0.7.0",**
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
**"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",**
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0"

**Error Flow** --> Bottom Navigation --> Any Screen with react-native-paper-tabs implementation -(Crashes with error)--> Switch back to any Bottom Navigation tab.

Thanks in advance.